# How can I show the flag field using Twig?

Tags: theming, 8, flags

I created a twig template for my node.

If I want to show the body field, I use `{{ content.field_body }}`. Similarly, how can I show the flag field?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it.

Flag machine name: `bookmark`

Then we can use `{{ content.flag_bookmark }}` in `node.html.twig` to show bookmark flag .